# Visual studio Ultimate 2013 slow start on debug

Tags: performance, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have installed visual studio 2013 Ultimate on Windows 8 enterprise edition.
When  I start debugging an mvc project (which pretty empty) : it takes 27 seconds to start the debugging. I assume it's because IIS express 8 is loading symbols and hangs somewhere.

I have tried an empty mvc project and it starts in 10 seconds : which is very unacceptable.

I have tried :
- deleting all breakpoints
- enabling just my code
- unchecking symbols downloading from microsoft servers and downloading them on a local folder on the computer
- disabling intellitrace (was already disabled when i went to see)
- disabling just-in-time (was already disabled when i went to see)
- unplugging the ethernet cable (yes, i am pretty desperate)
- no antivirus is turned on

The first request (when i launch debugging) always take 27 seconds according to glimpse. The controller run under 1 second which is "acceptable". All the next requests are fine.

But I can't work with the 27 seconds each time I launch debugging.
Can someone help me ? I do not know what to do next.

My computer is a dual core 3Ghz with 4 Go of Ram and a 7200 rpm hd. I don't think it's hardware related.

Thank you very much.

UPDATE :

As soon as I start to use NLog in the code, it takes 30 sec to launch the debug mode.
If I comment all the place where I log something, It takes 10 sec. Sometimes less.

How much time you guys take to launch the debug mode ?

Comment: trying with page inspector or different browser. was it same?

Comment: I've tried it on chrome, firefox, ie and page inspector. All of them with updated to their last version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quit possible you are referencing dead or slow symbol path. For example, you're at home but accessing a symbol path on company's server. Check it under Tools -> Options -> Debug -> Symbol. If it's ok, check your system as follows.

1. Make sure there is no other process that runs out of your hardware resources.
2. First check if CPU usage is too high after staring debugging. If CPU usage is too high, use Process Explorer to check what activities VS Is performing. If they are in an extension thread, disable that extension. If they are in VS own thread, it's most likely a VS bug you can report to MS.
3. Check if memory usage is too high. If VS memory usage is too high, given that you just start simple debugging, it's a VS bug.
4. If both CPU and memory are ok, it's probably related to IO operation. Use Process Monitor to check which files are being accessed, especially files on remote machine.

This is how I troubleshoot the same problem on my machine. Hope it help you.

Comment: Hi ! My hardware is fine. The cpu, memory and hd performance are ok : vs 2013 is not eating my computer alive.

Comment: @user3448717, IO problem doesn't only mean VS is eating whole disk space, or too many IO activists, a single remote file access can also kill your performance.

Comment: Hi ! My hardware is fine. The cpu, memory and hd performance are ok : vs 2013 is not eating my computer alive. But I used process monitor as suggested and found out that iisexpress is trying to create a file for NLog somewhere in the windows directory and gets and error : file not found. So I removed NLog and now it starts in 10 sec ! But now i am just wondering if I can go further because there's a bunch of "file locked" from iisexpress in process monitor ! How much time do your vs take to launch debugging mode ?

Comment: As I can see from process monitor, there is no remote file access. Everything is local.

Comment: For example : 8:23:31.6864670 PM iisexpress.exe 7032 CreateFile C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll PATH NOT FOUND Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a